# Complex Machine handling through VR controller

Tags: unity, c#, virtual-reality, htc-vive

I have a very [**Complex Machine**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RTHzLuEJGd4&feature=youtu.be) which I want to operate through my VR controller (HTC Vive Controller). As you can see its short animated video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RTHzLuEJGd4&feature=youtu.be). I want to pull the machine cover through VR controller which is easy to do but i want to scale and pull some of the other related objects of the machine too (like spring, piston etc, you can see in the video) as i pull its cover through VR controller.

The problem is that i am unable to do this using Joints and Animation play. I almost tried anything but nothing worked for me. My question how can i imitate animation all work through code or through physics. Like if i pull an object the rest related object should be stretched like chain. And piston should open or closed according to force.

Comment: Can you break down the question to a specific behavior i.e one part of the machine?

Comment: Yes the Pull the handle and the spring will streatch

Comment: have u check the video?

Comment: Yeah, it sounds like something you can do with frame by frame animation and interpolation.

Comment: Animation and interpolation.? how. animation is already create which consist of 12 seconds.

Comment: What was your solution?

Comment: nothing, unable to make it happen with VR controller. whats up?